# setTheme fails and falls back to default

Tags: android

I am writing a sample application which sets the theme using:

```
getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

Most of the time it works fine but sometime it fails and shows default theme, is this a known issue?

Comment: Where are you setting the theme? You may have to do it before calling `setContentView`

Comment: Yes i used it before calling setContentView,it takes default theme rarely,most of the time it works fine